# Columns from multiple table with same value returning wrong count of data when selecting multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, multiple-columns

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT
    columnA,
    columnB
FROM
    "table" A JOIN "table" B ON a.ID = b.ID
    WHERE a.column in ('value1','value2')
       AND SUBSTR(b.column,7,6) in ('value1','value2')
)
```

Here, when I enter a single value then I get the correct count but when I enter multiple values, I am getting a wrong count. For example, entering only **value 1** gives a count of 1241 rows and entering only **value 2** gives me a count of 0. I am expecting to enter both the values and get the sum of results from both values. But somehow due to a weird combination of values, I am getting more results than required instead of just 1241 rows.

I tried something like `where (a.column,SUBSTR(b.column,7,9)) in ('value1','value2')` but it did not work!

Comment: I doubt this is valid syntax

Comment: There is no '=' hence it is not comparing any column with a tuple @scaisEdge. I have talked about the expected result and what I am trying to do with the code above

Comment: This is a valid syntax and its working perfectly if I just pass a single value to the list of values @dneoth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what you want from your sample, but from what I gather you might have something like column being 'value1' in table A and 'value2' in table B. I think you need to change your code like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT
    columnA,
    columnB
FROM
    "table" A JOIN "table" B 
    ON a.ID = b.ID
      AND SUBSTR(b.column,7,6)=a.column
    WHERE a.column in ('value1','value2')

)
```

Comment: Been scratching my head for few hours on this. I did not know we could have two conditions to join tables. Such a simple and elegant solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: WHERE filters the joined result, ON instructs the joining. There are no two conditions, there is only one, combining two filters with an AND operator.

Answer (score 0):

Did yo try?

```
SELECT Sum(COUNT(x.columnA) + Count(x.columnb)) FROM (
SELECT
    columnA,
    columnB
FROM
    "table" A JOIN "table" B ON a.ID = b.ID
    WHERE a.column in ('value1','value2')
       AND SUBSTR(b.column,7,6) in ('value1','value2')
)x
```

Comment: Just tried it. Got an error : ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY
00978. 00000 -  "nested group function without GROUP BY"

Comment: Then try adding:  )x GROUP BY COUNT(x.columnA), COUNT(x.columnb)